# ThrowForNonSuccess causing 'Cannot perform binding on null reference' when using await

Tags: c#, json, .net

I've got a series of functions and methods to authenticate to a web service and control various hardware parameters.

Of which, almost all of them are async - aside from the ones where I'm specifically steering some parameters.

Where I've come unstuck over the last few days (and finally can see now) is that I have set a new value, sent it to the server, and am waiting for a boolean to come back to tell me if it's successful.

What's worse - is that if I'm explicitly awaiting everything I still get the same error.

I'm got it called from a timer, so I can consolidate all updates into a single JSON object, and correctly serialise it for the endpoint.

```
private async void SendTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var timer = sender as Timer;
    timer.Stop();
    if (Device.JsonToSend != null && Device.JsonToSend.Count > 0)  //ensure I've got a valid dict of endpoints and JSON updates
    {
        foreach (var json in Device.JsonToSend)
        {
            //Key is path, Value is payload.
            
            if(await Device.putValue(json))  //true if update was successful
            {
                await Device.readConfigJsonFromServer(this);
                await Device.readStatusJsonFromServer(this);
            }
            logger.Debug($"JSON to Send:\n{json}");
        }

    }
    Device.JsonToSend = new Dictionary<string, JObject>();
    timer.Start();

}
```

Timer above, putValue below.

```
public async Task<bool> putValue(KeyValuePair<string, JObject> json)
{
    // Initialization.  
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
    };
    // Prepare JSON - serialise CONFIG token

    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json.Value.SelectToken("config"));
    dynamic tempJson = json.Value;
    tempJson.Value.SelectToken("config").Replace(s);


    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        // Access test instance
        client.BaseAddress = SNPDeviceUri;
        string putPath = "/api/elements/" + SNPDeviceUri.Host + json.Key; // construct my putValue query
        putPath += "/?partial=true";

        int retryCount = 3;
        do
        {
            --retryCount;
            // Setting content type.  
            HttpResponseMessage putResponse = null;
            try
            {
                //stuff
            }
            ...
                else if(putResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //DeviceModel.CommsStatus = DeviceState.Connected;
                    logger.Trace($"PUT Succeeded to {SNPDeviceUri.Host}{putPath}\n\t{putResponse.StatusCode}:{putResponse.ReasonPhrase}\n\n\t{json.Value.ToString()}\n");
                    return true;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            } while (retryCount > 0);
            
         
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Even if I declare a boolean explicitly for await Device.putValue - I still get the same error - Cannot perform binding on null reference.

I think I've spent way too much time looking at this, and have evidently done something wrong.

Any thoughts?  Originally posted it on the software engineering site but I think I will get a better response here.

Stacktrace:

```
2021/01/13 14:31:59.167 :+: driver_template.App.CriticalError :+: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at driver_template.model.SNPDevice.<putValue>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at driver_template.model.SNPElement.<SendTimer_Elapsed>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

The underlying issue was masked - it looks like it's httpclient

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `dynamic` in the first place... without that, I suspect you'd have a rather simpler `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I changed all the calls to use a static HTTPClient (which failed - the endpoint was has keepalives disabled) so I rewrote everything as synchronous blocks - which now works successfully.